# Removing elements from a list if specific property is found within another list

Tags: javascript

I have two lists of objects that mostly contain different attributes. However, one attribute between them is similar. I am using this to verify that one list contain no object with a property that exists within an object found in the other list.

Assume `childrenA` is a list of objects containing attributes `name`, `age`, `weight` and that `childrenB` is a list of objects containing attributes `name`, `eyeColor`, `hairColor`.

To filter `childrenA` so that it does not contain objects with the same name as those in `childrenB`, I do:

```
childrenA = childrenA.filter(function(childA) {
    return childrenB.some(function(childB) {
        return childA.name !== childB.name;
    });
});
```

childrenA still, however, shares names of childrenB. Is the use of filter/some incorrect in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, since `.some` will return true if its callback is true for *any* element, it's enough that merely one member of `childrenB` not have the same name (which isn't what you want).

Consider using the related `.every` method instead:

(in plain english, this checks that *every* member of `childrenB` has a different name than `childA`):

```
childrenA = childrenA.filter(function(childA) {
    return childrenB.every(function(childB) {
        return childA.name !== childB.name;
    });
});
```

Or, you could negate the return of `.some` and check for name equality instead:

(Again, in english, this checks that there is *not some* member of `childrenB` with the same name as `childA`. You should be able to see how this is just a different form of the same check above)

```
childrenA = childrenA.filter(function(childA) {
    return !childrenB.some(function(childB) { // <-- note the negation
        return childA.name === childB.name; // <-- note the ===
    });
});
```